# execve ENOMEM ( Cannot allocate memory ) Error when execute some x64 binary

Tags: ubuntu, binary, execve

When I execute some statically linked binary in ubuntu 17.10,
other binaries are okay but specific some binary is problem.

```
gdb-peda$ x/15i 0x4000f0
   0x4000f0:    push   0x400105
   0x4000f5:    push   0x0
   0x4000f7:    xor    rax,rax
   0x4000fa:    mov    edx,0x10000
   0x4000ff:    mov    rsi,rsp
   0x400102:    xor    rdi,rdi
   0x400105:    syscall 
   0x400107:    mov    eax,0x1
   0x40010c:    mov    edx,0x1000
   0x400111:    pop    rsi
   0x400112:    mov    edi,0x1
   0x400117:    syscall 
   0x400119:    mov    eax,0x3c
   0x40011e:    ret
```

All code is like above one.
If I run this binary, I got the following error statement:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/hitcon/Desktop# ./biglittle 
Segmentation fault
```

I trace it with strace because this binary is statically linked,
I got this.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/hitcon/Desktop# strace -fFi ./biglittle 
[00007f9eaed12fa7] execve("./biglittle", ["./biglittle"], [/* 53 vars */]) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
[00007f9eaed12fa7] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=NULL} ---
[????????????????] +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can somebody give me advice to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same `strace` on one single special binary. Let's name than binary `foo.elf`.

When run **in docker**, `foo.elf` segfaults* in kernelspace, way before flow control reaches the ELF entrypoint. Exactly like you show: `execve` returns ENOMEM, and then the `strace` process itself receives that weird SIGSEGV with `si_code=SI_KERNEL`.

<sup>*More accurately, it's not `foo.elf` process that segfaults (that one never even starts running) — it is its post-fork() parent process that gets the SIGSEGV.</sup>

However, `foo.elf` runs fine on the host system!

Puzzling.

---

So this is what I found in my case. My `foo.elf` executable is statically linked:

```
⚓  file foo.elf
foo.elf: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

— which means that it uses no shared libraries (`.so`). That in turn, means that the ELF file does not request the dynamic linker, `ld.so`, as its *interpreter*, via the `INTERP` Program Header (a.k.a. segment):

```
⚓  readelf --segments foo.elf

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x14b5b0
There are 3 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000100000 0x0000000000100000
                 0x000000000004bddb 0x000000000004bddb  R E    10000
  LOAD           0x000000000000bc18 0x00000000000fbc18 0x00000000000fbc18
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     1000
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RWE    0
```

— see, there's no `INTERP` section. Compare with a baseline dynamic executable:

```
⚓  readelf --segments /bin/ls

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x404b48
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000001f8 0x00000000000001f8  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000193fc 0x00000000000193fc  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x000000000001a328 0x000000000061a328 0x000000000061a328
                 0x00000000000012d8 0x0000000000001ff8  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000000000001ada8 0x000000000061ada8 0x000000000061ada8
                 0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200  RW     8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x0000000000016650 0x0000000000416650 0x0000000000416650
                 0x0000000000000744 0x0000000000000744  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000000000001a328 0x000000000061a328 0x000000000061a328
                 0x0000000000000cd8 0x0000000000000cd8  R      1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
 [...]
```

So that's correct.

... But wait! What is this?

```
⚓  file foo.elf
foo.elf: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

And this??

```
⚓ readelf --file-header foo.elf
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              DYN (Shared object file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x14b5b0
  Start of program headers:          64 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           56 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         3
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         0
  Section header string table index: 0
```

... Aah-huh! Our executable claims to be a shared library !

I.e. the `e_type` field of its ELF file header is set to `ET_DYN` (3), instead of `ET_EXEC` (2).

That is sort of weird, but generally acceptable: the ELF format permits double-duty binaries, which you can both `dlopen()` as a library and `exec()` as a program. The dynamic linker (`ld.so`), *I think*, is exactly like that.

So back to my `foo.elf`: it was produced with `-fPIE` CFLAG and `-pie` link flag, and later postprocessed with a couple of ELF transformation tools. PIE stands for *position-independent executable*; and for me it was enough to remove `-fPIE -pie` to get `e_type == ET_EXEC` binary:

```
foo.elf.nopie: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, stripped
```

And this one works great. No segfaults, in docker or otherwise. Woo-hoo, puzzle solved! Hope this helps to someone out there :)